# How to get thumbnail of video which is uploaded on Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

We have a .NET project.

We're uploading video files directly to S3.

How can we create a thumbnail of the video which is located in S3 Storage.

Which service should we use, and can we do that in javasript or using AWSSDK library.

Since the video is not uploaded to our servers we need to find a way using services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AWS Developer Forums: How to create only one thumbnail per video](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=492897), it appears that you could:

- Use **Amazon Elastic Transcoder** to convert the video into thumbnails
- Specify a huge thumbnail interval to force it to output only one thumbnail per video

Comment: I'm looking for a AWSSDK reference or javascript reference for this job.

Comment: Create a pipeline that will sit there always awaiting jobs ([Settings that You Specify When You Create an Elastic Transcoder Job - Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/job-settings.html)) — you can do this in the console or with `CreatePipeline()`. Then submit a job with `CreateJob()`. If you are using Node.js, see: [Class: AWS.ElasticTranscoder — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder.html)